# Webelement not identified in IE

Tags: java, css, selenium

A WebElement is not identified in IE whereas it is identified in Chrome and Mozilla.

Below is the HTML code of the WebElement which I'm trying to identify

```
<div class="formRow">
<label>Fleet</label>
<span id="lblBRVFleet" style="font-weight: bold">598978 - LAi Website Automation</span>
<input name="ctl00$cphMain$RentalVehicle$hdnBRVFleet" type="hidden" id="hdnBRVFleet" value="598978" />
</div>
```

I have captured the SPAN in my OR.properties as shown below

```
lblFleetValue=#lblBRVFleet
```

My code to identify the object is below

```
currentElement=new WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(OR.getProperty(lblFleetValue))));
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: input is hidden so selenium might be throwing exception after waiting for 30 seconds. Add stacktrace if you are getting any exception

Comment: Hi Karna,I'm trying to identify the span and not the input.

Comment: What do you mean by identified in Chrome and Firefox, vs not identified in IE?  Is there a difference noted when you inspect the elements in each of the browsers?